# Input of BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, input

Among the brushless DC motor, is there a motor with two input wire?
I thought that bldc motors with hall sensors should have 2 input, but it was hard to find such one. Is it wrong concept about bldc motor?

Comment: Explain why you think a BLDC with hall sensors would only have two inputs.

Comment: Consider a bundled motor + motor controller (that's the bit that turns the 2 wire supply into the 3 motor drive wires). How would you control the speed/direction? At least another wire in addition to the two supplies.

Comment: No, they don't have 2 wires. Perhaps you could get some sort of fixed speed controller that has a 2 wire input, but the motor itself will not have 2 wires.

Comment: I guess it depends on if you cosider the commutation electronics to be part of the motor or not.  there's plenty of 2 wire DC fans built around BLDC motors.